# Unable to connect to postgres SQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, maven

I'm using `Spring + Maven + Hibernate` and want to run tests in a `PostgreSQL` environment.

After adding the proper dependencies and changing my xml files I'm getting the following error when running `mvn clean install` in cmd:

```
Coult not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

And the output log of the test is something like:

```
 Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 9, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.695 sec <<< FAILURE!
testFlush(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.AccountAllocationIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 15.432 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:513)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:358)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    ... 54 more
testMarkerMethod(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.AccountAllocationIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 1.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:513)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:358)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    ... 54 more
testFindAccountAllocation(com.mms.pone.portal.domain.AccountAllocationIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 1.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.startTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:513)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.startNewTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:164)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:358)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 38 more
```

Obviously there's a problem with my login credentials, but I'm not sure what exactly.

My `database.properties` file:

```
########################################################
#                                                      #
#  This configuration is used for unit-testing only.   #
#                                                      #
########################################################


database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
database.username=postgres
database.password=
```

persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

`ApplicationContext.xml` file

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/test-database.properties"/>

<bean id="externalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property>
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath*:META-INF/conf/configuration.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>

    <!-- OMITTED FOR THE SAKE OF CLARITY AND SPACE -->

     <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="1" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/test-persistence.xml" />
    </bean>
```

I'm just starting out with Spring Tool Suite (Spring + Maven + Hibernate) so any help would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: are you sure you're not missing the port in the url? database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test (just guessing)

Comment: +1 for actually including the full exception. Thanks.

Comment: @CraigRinger I'll try, see if stack overflow allows me to add those extra chars

Comment: @Eugen I'm saying thanks for doing what you've done, not "add more". It's nice (and rare) for someone to actually include the full exception text.

Comment: @Eugen what does `psql -h localhost -U postgres test` do? How about `psql -U postgres test` (without the `-h localhost`) ? Have you checked the `listen_addresses` parameter in `postgresql.conf` to verify that the server is listening on TCP/IP?

Comment: This is not a password problem. `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` means exactly that - the server wasn't listening. Make sure PostgreSQL is actually running. If that doesn't work, post your `pg_hba.conf` so we can check that.

Comment: BTW, the full error message from your exception is *Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.* . It's telling you the next step.

Comment: @TomAnderson `pg_hba.conf` does not control which IPs/ports the server listens on, only how it treats connections it does get. You'd get a `no pg_hba.conf entry for ...` error if this were a `pg_hba.conf` setup issue. It's failing before that; it's just not listening on the target IP/port.

Comment: what returns command  `ps -ef | grep postgres` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Fair enough. I have vague memories of having to tweak `pg_hba.conf` to make TCP/IP connections possible in the past, but evidently that was a different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are getting a connection refused error, you should check if postgres is running/listening on localhost. You can check is postgres is listening on 5432 port using `netstat -a` command.

Comment: If you're on Linux, `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep postgres` will tell you where PostgreSQL *is* listening, if it's listening.

Comment: @Eugen Well, is it running then? What about the `psql` commands I gave in the main comments? Are there any `postgres` processes?

Comment: @Eugen then you need to start postgres/see why it is not starting properly.

Comment: @dan Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do now. I've got a lot of servers running and I think they're conflicting. Should work in a couple of minutes